# How can i convert entity character(Escape character) to HTML in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to  convert entity character(Escape character) to HTML in QT, please help me....

i.e: I want to replace `&quot;` with `"`, `&gt;` with `>`

=====This is my code that not worked====

```
   QString MyApp::ReplaceString(const QString Data, const QString &Before, const      QString &After)
{

    QString Result = Data;
    Result.replace(Before, After, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    return Result;
}
```

========

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QByteArray data=pReply->readAll();
QString str = codec->toUnicode((const char *)data);

str = Qt::escape(str);
str = ReplaceString(str, "&quot;", "\"");   

str = ReplaceString(str,"&gt;", ">");
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please add  some examples of what you want converted to what.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for your reply, I've been add some code

Comment: Those replacements work. Are you sure you should be `escape`ing your input?

Comment: @Matt: I've been getting result from http://fa.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&page=%D3%E1%C7%E3

Comment: Use an XML parser! Those results contain both escaped and unescaped symbols.

Comment: @Mat:Is it possible for you to show me with example?

Comment: Please do some research. "Qt xml parser" in your favorite search engine will  give you lots of examples.

Comment: I can't help myself but shouldn't you actually be unescaping?

Comment: `&quot;` and `&gt;` *are* HTML. There's nothing to convert. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure I understand what you want, just guessing. You can use QTextDocument. Try something like this:

```
QTextDocument text;
text.setHtml("&lt;&gt;&quot;");
QString plain = text.toPlainText();
qDebug("%s.", qPrintable(plain));
```

Remember that QTextDocument needs the gui module.

Comment: The reverse also works for creating HTML-encoded versions of plaintext strings.  Nice!

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that it introduces QtGui dependency, so not useful if you have a console app.

Comment: How about this kind of characters "\xE6\x97\xA0\xE8\xAE\xBF\xE9\x97\xAE\xE6\x9D\x83\xE9\x99\x90\". I know QUrl.decode can decode them, but when they are not in a URL but in html, this way seems not graceful. Edit: I just find a way -- QString::fromUtf8(data).

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
QString escaped= 
QString(myhtml).replace("&","&amp;").replace(">","&gt;").replace("<","&lt;");
```

Comment: The OP asked for reverse convertion

Answer (score 1):

Test `escape()` function:

```
 QString plain = "#include <QtCore>"
 QString html = Qt::escape(plain);
 // html == "#include &lt;QtCore&gt;"
```

and `convertFromPlainText()` function:

```
QString Qt::convertFromPlainText ( const QString & plain, WhiteSpaceMode mode = WhiteSpacePre )
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello to convert non ASCII character to &#*XXX*; (where *XXX* is a number):

```
/***************************************************************************//*!
* @brief Encode all non ASCII characters into &#...;
* @param[in] src        Text to analyze
* @param[in,opt] force  Force the characters "list" to be converted.
* @return ASCII text compatible. 
*
* @note Original code: http://www.qtforum.org/article/3891/text-encoding.html
*
* @warning Do not forget to use QString::fromUtf8()
*/
QString encodeEntities( const QString& src, const QString& force=QString() )
{
    QString tmp(src);
    uint len = tmp.length();
    uint i = 0;
    while( i<len )
    {
        if( tmp[i].unicode() > 128 || force.contains(tmp[i]) ){
            QString rp = "&#"+QString::number(tmp[i].unicode())+";";
            tmp.replace(i,1,rp);
            len += rp.length()-1;
            i += rp.length();
        }else{
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}


/***************************************************************************//*!
* @brief Allows decode &#...; into UNICODE (utf8) character.
* @param[in] src    Text to analyze
* @return UNICODE (utf8) text.
*
* @note Do not forget to include QRegExp
*/
QString decodeEntities( const QString& src )
{
    QString ret(src);
    QRegExp re("&#([0-9]+);");
    re.setMinimal(true);

    int pos = 0;
    while( (pos = re.indexIn(src, pos)) != -1 )
    {
        ret = ret.replace(re.cap(0), QChar(re.cap(1).toInt(0,10)));
        pos += re.matchedLength();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Basic usage:

```
qDebug() << encodeEntities(QString::fromUtf8("éà@<>hello the world €"),QString("<>"));
// Will print: &#233;&#224;@&#60;&#62;hello the world &#8364;
qDebug() << decodeEntities("a&#223;&#233;plop&#233;&#224;&#231;&#234;&#8364;");
// Will print: hello world
```