# What tools in Qt are there to decode HTML 4 entities?

Tags: qt

I have an input QString that has HTML 4 entities, like `&otilde;` that I’d like to decode. But I can’t find any facilities in Qt to do so. Is there a way to do so in Qt? If possible I’d like to avoid `QTextDocument` so I don’t have to bring in QtGui.

The HTML 4 entities are listed in this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I have looked a bit around.

I found this [SO: How can i convert entity character(Escape character) to HTML in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696962/7478597). However, it uses `QTextDocument` (which is part of GUI) what OP wants to prevent.

The [doc. of `QTextDocument::setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#setHtml) doesn't mention anything specific whether something is used which could be accessed directly (and is even part of the Qt core). Hence, I had a look into source code. I started with [`QTextDocument::setHtml()` on woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextdocument.cpp.html#_ZN13QTextDocument7setHtmlERK7QString) and followed the bread crumbs.

Finally, I ended up in [`qtbase/src/gui/text/qtexthtmlparser.cpp`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtexthtmlparser.cpp.html#_ZN15QTextHtmlParser11parseEntityEv):

```
QString QTextHtmlParser::parseEntity()
{
    const int recover = pos;
    int entityLen = 0;
    QStringRef entity;
    while (pos < len) {
        QChar c = txt.at(pos++);
        if (c.isSpace() || pos - recover > 9) {
            goto error;
        }
        if (c == QLatin1Char(';'))
            break;
        ++entityLen;
    }
    if (entityLen) {
        entity = QStringRef(&txt, recover, entityLen);
        QChar resolved = resolveEntity(entity);
        if (!resolved.isNull())
            return QString(resolved);
        if (entityLen > 1 && entity.at(0) == QLatin1Char('#')) {
            entity = entity.mid(1); // removing leading #
            int base = 10;
            bool ok = false;
            if (entity.at(0).toLower() == QLatin1Char('x')) { // hex entity?
                entity = entity.mid(1);
                base = 16;
            }
            uint uc = entity.toUInt(&ok, base);
            if (ok) {
                if (uc >= 0x80 && uc < 0x80 + (sizeof(windowsLatin1ExtendedCharacters)/sizeof(windowsLatin1ExtendedCharacters[0])))
                    uc = windowsLatin1ExtendedCharacters[uc - 0x80];
                QString str;
                if (QChar::requiresSurrogates(uc)) {
                    str += QChar(QChar::highSurrogate(uc));
                    str += QChar(QChar::lowSurrogate(uc));
                } else {
                    str = QChar(uc);
                }
                return str;
            }
        }
    }
error:
    pos = recover;
    return QLatin1String("&");
}
```

A table of named entities can be found in the same source file:

```
static const struct QTextHtmlEntity { const char name[9]; quint16 code; } entities[]= {
    { "AElig", 0x00c6 },
    { "AMP", 38 },
```

...

```
    { "zwj", 0x200d },
    { "zwnj", 0x200c }
};
Q_STATIC_ASSERT(MAX_ENTITY == sizeof entities / sizeof *entities);
```

These are bad news for OP:

1. The API of the `QTextHtmlParser` is private:

   ```
   //
   //  W A R N I N G
   //  -------------
   //
   // This file is not part of the Qt API.  It exists purely as an
   // implementation detail.  This header file may change from version to
   // version without notice, or even be removed.
   //
   // We mean it.
   //
   ```
2. and it's part of Qt GUI.

If OP insists to prevent GUI dependencies, the only other chance I see is to duplicate the code (or just to re-implement it from scratch).